# Did Harbhajan Singh Yogi say "... to learn something - read about it ..."?

Tags: quotes

Did Harbhajan Singh Yogi say

> If you want to learn something - read about it; understand something -
>   write about it; master something - teach it.

Wikiquote has it as [unsourced](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk%3aHarbhajan_Singh_Yogi), and there's an [unsourced claim](http://www.ericlee.asia/60/to-learn-read-to-know-write-to-master-teach) that a variant, "To learn, read. To know, write. To master, teach." is a Hindu proverb.

Comment: I guess your question is, not whether he said it, but whether he invented it, i.e. was the first to say it?

Comment: @ChrisW it's quite possible that even if the quote existed, he hasn't said it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote is noted on the [official site](http://www.kundaliniresearchinstitute.org/faq.htm) that publishes and certifies on his behalf,

[Kundalini Research Institute](http://www.kundaliniresearchinstitute.org/teachertraining.htm)

```
“If you want to learn something, read about it. 
 If you want to understand something, write about it. 
 If you want to master something, teach it.”   
   —Yogi Bhajan
```

<sup>(see the bottom of that page)</sup>

If this is implied in other ways in older texts that remains to be confirmed.